# How to install phalcon version 2

Tags: phalcon

I have some applications built on phalcon version 2, but since the release of the version 3, new installations of phalcon default to version 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install phalcon from source, but instead of build from the master branch switch the branch to the 2.0.x branch.

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon
git remote set-branches origin '2.0.x'
git fetch --depth 1 origin 2.0.x
git checkout 2.0.x
cd build
./install
```

I created this gist to make this easier - https://gist.github.com/goke-epapa/c325da217296ec4880850972be955bf0

**UPDATE**

I've been told that the above snippet installs version 2.0.10, so the snippet below is specifically for version 2.0.13

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon
git remote set-branches origin 'phalcon-v2.0.13'
git fetch --depth 1 origin phalcon-v2.0.13
git checkout phalcon-v2.0.13
cd build
./install
```

**Update** 
Both code snippets were missing the `cd cphalcon` command so I modified the snippets.

Comment: git remote set-branches origin '2.0.x'
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Hi @AbdulWaheed, Thanks for noticing this, I've added the missing command.

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-172-00-00-84:~/cphalcon$ git checkout phalcon-v2.0.13
error: pathspec 'phalcon-v2.0.13' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: do we need to add any extension in php/ini file.? @Adegoke