# how to install specific phalcon framework version 2.0.?

Tags: linux, installation, phalcon

i have a application which is working fine with version 2.0

for that i am unable to install phalcon version 2.0 only latest version version 3.2.2 is installing..

so how can i install v 2.0..??

Installation source: https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux

```
curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install php5-phalcon
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:phalcon(2.0x)/legacy
```

This following similar question is not helped me out from the issue.
[How to install phalcon version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259735/how-to-install-phalcon-version-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well don't see last package version for phalcon 2.0.x on packagecloud or launchpad so you simply need to use git:

```
git clone https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon
cd cphalcon
git checkout 2.0.x
cd build
sudo ./install
```

Add to php.ini - `extension=phalcon.so`

Answer (score 2):

First, here is the official 2.0 install docs [Installation Phalcon 2.0](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/2.0.0/reference/install.html) The docs you posted are for our current version which is compatible with php7 I am not sure how that will work with 2.0.x

The only amendment I would make to [How to install phalcon version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259735/how-to-install-phalcon-version-2) would be to use the release from github like [phalcon-2.0.13-stable](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/phalcon-v2.0.13) that is the easiest way to select a major version so if 2.0.13 isn't appropriate you can likely find the version you need on github. [Phalcon Releases](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases?before=v2.0.13)

Comment: witht that documentation v3 is installing because it is latest

Comment: Yep thats why you need to use that to help with the required dependencies for 2.0 and then download a 2.0 release

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Phalcon version at the end of the install command. It should only allow versions that are compatible with your PHP version installed.

```html
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
// sudo apt-get install php$php_v-phalcon$phalcon_v
sudo apt-get install php7.2-phalcon3
```